# Can't find dependency? spring-modules-sandbox

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, hsqldb

Well I need to create hssldb before application context load. I found how to do that with spring-modules-sandbox
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?14419-HSQL-server-wrapped-into-a-Spring-bean&p=19830#post19830

Add maven dependency:

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-modules-sandbox</artifactId>
 <version>0.8</version> 
</dependency>
```

when compiling get following warning:

```
Downloading: http://10.10.1.33:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springmodules/spring-modules-sandbox/0.8/spring-modules-sandbox-0.8.pom 
[WARNING] The POM for org.springmodules:spring-modules-sandbox:jar:0.8 is missing, no dependency information available
```

but succesfull.
 then try to use bean:

```
 <bean id="dataBase" class="org.springmodules.db.hsqldb.ServerBean" scope="singleton" lazy-init="false"> 
<!--<property name="dataSource" ref="idtSimulatorDataSource" >-->
 <!--&lt;!&ndash;<ref local=""/>&ndash;&gt;--> <!--&lt;!&ndash;
<ref local= "idtSimulatorDataSource"/>&ndash;&gt;--> <!--</property>--> 
<property name="serverProperties" > 
<props> 
<prop key="server.port">9101</prop>
 <prop key="server.database.0">./idt_simulatorsdb</prop>
 <prop key="server.dbname.0">idt_simulatorsdb</prop>
 </props>
 </property> 
</bean>
```

And got the error during appcontext loading:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/HsqlProperties
```

google didn't help really need help

Answer (score 0):

`spring-modules-sandbox` uploaded to maven central on 20-Aug-2007!!! (*so I guess it is not spring 3.0 compatible*) does not have a `pom.xml` nor any dependency information in its `META-INF` directory.

So if you really want to use it, it looks like you need to add all the dependencies that needed by spring-modules-sandbox must be added by you explicit to the dependencies of your pom. One of that missing dependencies is the one that contains `org.hsqldb.HsqlProperties`
This class is contained in hsqldb 1.7:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Attention**: `org.hsqldb.HsqlProperties` is removed in hsqldb 1.8! So may the problem is that you use a too new version for spring-modules-sandbox

Comment: Thanx for response.
Actualy I don't need to use sandbox. I just wand to launch hsqldb server as spring bean.
Can you help me?

Comment: Same solution: add hsqldb 1.7.3.3

Comment: I'll ask my head is it a good solution but I suppose that it's not the best idea. Any way thanx

Comment: There is a solution! I just launch my server programmatically in functon with @BeforeClass Annotation. Function with such annotation starts before context load